# Behavior of Parallel.ForEach and arguments for lambda expressions

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parameter-passing

I have the following code:

```
public OrderInfo GetPreviousOrder(int customerId)
{
    using (var entities = new ContosoEntities())
    {
        var previousOrder = entities.Orders
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate)
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.CustomerId == customerId);

        var response = new OrderInfo
        {
            Customer = RetrieveCustomerInfo(customerId),
        };
        if (previousOrder != null)
        {
            response.FollowUps = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<OrderFollowUp>, OrderFollowUpData[]>(previousOrder.FollowUps);
            response.Appointments = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Appointment>, OrderAppointment[]>(previousOrder.Appointments);
            response.DiscussionTopics = previousOrder.DiscussionTopics.Select(discussionTopic => discussionTopic.Topic).ToArray();
        }

        var actions = new Action[]
        {
            () => response.Invoices = RetriveInvoices(customerId, previousOrder),
            () => response.Items = RetrieveItems(customerId, previousOrder)
        };
        Parallel.ForEach(actions, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, action => action());

        return response;
    }
}
```

In summary, this method gets the info of a customer's previous order. Most of the order info is stored in my project's database (accessed using Entity Framework), but a few things are pulled from another source (customer info, invoices and items).
Sometimes, when the `RetriveInvoices` method gets executed (and the customer had a previous order stored in our database), the value of the `previousOrder` variable passed is null. Likewise, some other times, it's the `RetrieveItems` method that gets a null value and some other times, the code behaves as (I) expected, meaning, the `previousOrder` variable actually has the info of the previous order passed to both methods. Both methods are being executed until their respective last line, there are no exceptions being thrown. And no, both methods only read the `previousOrder` variable.

Can somebody explain to me why I'm seeing this behavior?

Comment: Very interesting indeed. I am not seeing anything immediately obvious that might lead to the behaviour you describe. Just out of curiosity: are you still observing the same issue when using `Parallel.Invoke` (which is a better fit in this case)?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue on my PC, it happens on our QA server. Since we're very close to our deadline, as a (lame) fix I just replaced the Parallel.ForEach with sequential. Maybe in a later sprint I'll try to use Parallel.Invoke as suggested and see what happens.